# ES6 module paths when deployed across multiple web servers

Tags: django, es6-modules

ES6 modules are easy enough to leverage, however I am struggling with how to get them to work in both dev and prod. In dev, they're stored in Django's static folder, which means I can import them like this:

```
import { buildTable } from './customTable.js';
```

And in the html templates:

```
<script type="module">
    import { buildTable } from '../../static/customTable.js'
    example('hello world')
</script>
```

However, in prod, the static folder is on a different webserver, so these paths wont be the same. What is the best way to get these modules to load both in dev and prod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Django template syntax to import the js modules:

```
import { example } from '{% static "test.js" %}'
```